# How do I unbind a Marionette's listenTo?

Tags: events, backbone.js, marionette

If I listened to an event using `.listenTo()`, how do I unbind it?

In some code I am working on, I have something like:

```
class Something extends Marionette.CompositeView

    initialize: ->
        ...
        // listen to an event of a static object 
        @listenTo Something.dateRange, DateRange.EVENT_CHANGED, @_update
```

The problem appears to be when I switch between views, this event is not unbound, thus, it gets triggered more and more times as the view is reinitalized. Shouldn't Marionette unbind such events? If it doesn't, how do whats the reverse of `listenTo`? I guess I just put that in `onBeforeClose`

Comment: If you (or Marionette) call [`View#remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) then you don't need to `stopListening` yourself, the standard `remove` does it already (this is one of the reasons to prefer `listenTo` over `on` BTW).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh I think I got it ... its `stopListening` from `Backbone.Events` not Marionette. I was looking in the Marionette docs, the wrong place. The relevant information is within the [Backbone Events docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-stopListening).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `listenToOnce`. Now the event will only trigger ones if you initialize the class.